# Two methods of Traversing nodes and inserting at middle in linked lists

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

```
    void insert()
{   
    struct node *temp;
    struct node*pre=start,*count=start;
    int ps,i,c=0;
    printf("Enter the position where u want to insert\n");
    scanf("%d",&ps);
    if(ps==1)
        {insertbeg();}
    else
    {
     while(count!=0)
    {c++;
    count=count->link;}
            if(ps>c)
            {insertend(ps);}
                        else
                            {
                            temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                                if (temp==NULL)
                                {printf("Memory is full\n");}
                                else
                                {
                                for(i=1;i<ps;i++) //place1
                                {pre=pre->link;}  
                                temp->link=pre;//place2
                                pre=temp;//place3
                                printf("Enter the element to inserted\n");
                                scanf("%d",&temp->data);
                                }
                            }
    }
}
```

The code runs but whenever i insert any element at the middle position it doesn't show up using display function while inserting at the beginning(insertbeg()) and inserting at the end (insertend() ) work and display normally.
When i substitute the below lines in places 1,2&3 the elements are displayed normally.

```
for(i=1;i<ps-1;i++) 
temp->link=pre->link; 
pre->link=temp;
```

I want to know why is this happening since both set of statements seem equivalent.

Comment: No aparrent debugging, DCV.

Answer (score 1):

Place3 is where is the big difference. When you write `pre=temp` only the local variable `pre` is modified, not the previous node's link to the next node. This is why your linked list doesn't show up the new element.

Comment: since temp is a pointer what pre=temp should do is store temp's address in pointer variable pre(which is previous nodes link to to next node) then store data in temp->data which is the same as pre->data(since they are pointers to the same address)

Comment: Working with pointers could be a bit tricky sometimes. Just remember that every variable and struct's fields are stored at an unique address in memory. The previous node's link to the next node is stored at a different address than `pre`. Even if they have both the same value just before place3 (they both points at the same old node), changing the value of `pre` just make `pre` pointing elsewhere but doesn't change where the struct's field `next` of the previous node points.